# Pagination for two different actions in the same controller

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have an action called `index` and another one called `manage`, both in `PostsController`. I want to implement pagination for both, and I've set up this class attribute:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => array(
        'Post.created' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

then I'm using the pagination in my `index` action like so: `$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));`

This results in a URL like so: `http://dev/posts/page:2` which is fine.

However, when I try to use pagination in my `manage` action just like I did with `index` (`$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));`), the pagination links on my view redirect to the URL above, rather than the manage action.

Basically, Cake is getting confused because I'm using pagination twice in the same controller and it's redirecting both to the same URL. How can I make sure that the pagination for the `manage` action works properly?

Comment: I cannot see how your code above would handle a redirect... could you please post the code relevant to the redirect. Also wouldn't you just be able to add a variable within a conditional ex if index var = manage; if manage var = index and then just redirect to the variable?

Comment: When the pagination helper is used in a view it outputs page numbers, when you click them it redirects the user to the relevant page. My code works for the `index` action the way I want it to, the problem is that when I click the pagination numbers on the `manage` action's view, it redirects the user to the same page as the `index` action rather than the `manage` action. Here's my controller code: http://pastebin.com/uz5USqYJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the followings.

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Posts';
    public $paginate = array
    (
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => array
        (
            'Post.created' => 'desc'
        )
    );

    function index()
    {
        $this->Post->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
    }

    function manage()
    {
        $this->Post->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
    }
}
```

make changes in view file as defined below.

**index.ctp**

```
$options = array
(
    'url'=> array
    (
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'index'
     )
);
$paginator->options($options);
```

**manage.ctp**

```
$options = array
(
    'url'=> array
    (
        'controller' => 'posts', 
        'action' => 'manage'
     )
);
$paginator->options($options);
```

And you are done.